# Союз «да и» — нужны ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, согласование, союзы

*Факт строительства вала, да и само его наличие, не отражены в записях византийской церкви.*

Союз ***да и*** в этом предложении, как мне кажется, выполняет присоединительную функцию. Нужна ли вторая запятая? Если убрать это присоединение, то подлежащее ***факт*** не будет согласовываться со сказуемым ***не отражены***. Как вам видится пунктуация и согласование?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То, что это присоединительная конструкция, бесспорно, запятые нужны, а вот согласование, думаю, должно быть в единственном числе, как, например, у Л.Карпенко:

> Факт строительства вала, да и само его наличие, не отразился в
>   византийских летописях, поскольку вал был построен задолго до
>   возникновения первых греческих общин (да и по годам он старше
>   египетских пирамид).

https://maxpark.com/community/8/content/2077449

Comment: Людмила, да, это Леонид Карпенко. В еще не напечатанной книге у него это предложение выглядит так: "Факт строительства вала, да и само его наличие, не отраженО в записях византийской церкви, поскольку он был построен задолго до возникновения первых греческих общин и возникновения христианства". Средний род здесь относится к "наличию". С мужским родом предложение как-то не очень звучит. Скажите, а можно ли "факт" и "наличие" рассматривать как однородные подлежащие, не ставить вторую запятую и соответственно сказуемое поставить во мн. числе?

Comment: Тогда придётся убирать присоединение: Факт строительства вала и само его наличие не отражены в записях византийской церкви. Однородные так однородные, без присоединения.

Comment: Да, я так и сделаю, автор дает мне довольно большой простор в редактировании. Спасибо большое!